# Why concatenate the key a second time in HMAC?

Tags: hash, hmac

On Wikipedia it is said that HMAC is basically (without taking into account padding):

$H(key\ \Vert\ H(key\ \Vert\ message))$

where $\Vert$ denotes concatenation.

I understand the need to hash twice, but why concatenate the key a second time in the outter hashing?

Why not simply hash twice, but without reusing the key, like this:

$H( H(key\ \Vert\ message))$

A bit like Bitcoin's double-SHA, rumored to be done to prevent length-extension attacks.

Comment: silly me: I answered a clear duplicate.